# Node.js if statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning javascript & Node.js. For some reason this `IF` statement is not working as I would've expected...
I cannot figure out how to solve this...

**My code:**

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');                      //Set UTF charcode

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {                    //Event fires when there's input
    var readConsole = process.stdin.read();             //Receive the input from console

    if(readConsole != null) {
        readConsole.trim().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");   //Trim input and remove line breaks

        process.stdout.write('Input: ' + readConsole);  //Output the input

        if(readConsole == "quit") {
            process.exit();
        }
    }
});
```

But for some reason, whenever I type "quit" in the console, it does not respond.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Consider getting in the habit of using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @Joe white; why do I need to use 3 equals? I thought 1 was for setting variables, 2 was for if statements etc. and 3 for if statements with true or false? Isn't that the case??

Comment: `=` is indeed for assignment. `==` and `===` are both comparison operators; their behavior is identical except that `==` does type coercion, which is almost never a good thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/87399.

Comment: @JoeWhite Thanks! I never knew that! I'll start using that from now on! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `trim()` and `replace()` return a new string, but you are not assigning that value to any variable. You probably want to remove extra characters, not replace them with spaces (thanks @fvgs). Try:

```
readConsole = readConsole.trim().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
```

Comment: The replacement string should probably be `""`, otherwise the condition in the if statement will need to be `readConsole == "quit "`.

Comment: Owh, I did that at first. but removing the spaces worked this way too.... Anyway, thanks man 10/10!!